# Select all table rows with each selected row from another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have two tables, one is "stores" table, and the other one is "products" table.

Stores table:

```
-------------
| id | desc |
-------------
| 1  | st1  |
| 2  | st2  |
| 3  | st3  |
```

Products table:

```
-------------
| id | desc |
-------------
| 1  | pr1  |
| 2  | pr2  |
| 3  | pr3  |
```

I want to select all "stores", and all "products" with each store like that:

Result:

```
---------------------
| stores | products |
---------------------
|  st1   |   pr1    |
|  st1   |   pr2    |
|  st1   |   pr3    |

|  st2   |   pr1    |
|  st2   |   pr2    |
|  st2   |   pr3    |

|  st3   |   pr1    |
|  st3   |   pr2    |
|  st3   |   pr3    |
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Note that desc is a reserved word

Comment: @Strawberry, sure I knew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do: `SELECT Stores.desc AS stores, Products.desc AS products FROM Stores, Products`

Comment: Could you please clarify it for me? I can't understand the query and how it works, as I expected joins or where clause.

Comment: @CairoCoder this code just sorts and matches what you asked, if you want joins you need relations between tables which appearently you don't have.

Comment: @CarioCoder when no joins are specified, MySQL will automatically join all tables in the FROM clause, in all possible variations (i.e. matching all rows of each table with each row of all other tables)

Comment: @CarioCoder The two answers provided are semantically identical- both providing a Cartesian product, which is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cross Join like below:

```
 select stores.desc,products.desc from stores cross join products
```